# Vue router handle urls incorrectly in hash mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

My site is hosted on the IIS and accessable as `machinename/test/`.
When i try to open site as `machinename/test/` route become `machinename/test/#/`, and all assets are loading as expected.
But if i open as `machinename/test` route become `machinename/test#/`, and assets paths break.

How can i fix it? I want when going to `machinename/test` the path was becoming `machinename/test/#/`.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky, but this should work:

Before the `VueRouter` instantiation, add:

```js
if (!window.location.pathname.endsWith('test/')) {
  window.location.replace(
    `${window.location.href}`.replace(
      window.location.pathname, 
      `${window.location.pathname}`.replace(
        '/test', 
        '/test/')
      )
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

GO to your routes.js and change this

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: []
```

to this

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
routes:[]
})
```

Rebuild your project and re-upload

Vue reference: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Thank you for response, but i looking for solution in the hash mode. Does it exist?